# Limit to infinity of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral with Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Prove that for every fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$$
\mathbb{E}_x \left[  \exp\big(\int_0^t  \frac{1}{1+B_s^2} ds \big) \right] 
$$

goes to $\infty$ as $t\to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: By Jensen's Inequality $E_xe^{\int_0^{t} \frac 1 {1+B_s^{2}} ds} \geq exp(E_x{\int_0^{t} \frac 1 {1+B_s^{2}} ds})$. So it is enough to show that  $E_x{\int_0^{t} \frac 1 {1+B_s^{2}} ds} \to \infty$. We can interchange the integral and the expectation and write down $E_x \frac 1 {1+B_s^{2}}$ using Gaussian density. I will let you take over from here.